# Writing to InfluxDB using Go client results in random errors

Tags: go, influxdb

I am using the golang influx v2 client library to write to my influxdb. My code, based on the reference example in the client documentation is fairly straightforward:

```
func SaveMetricsToInflux(id string, rs Resultset, mtype string) {
    defer conf.Trace()()
    // Create a new HTTPClient
    c, err := client.NewHTTPClient(client.HTTPConfig{
        Addr:     conf.InfluxEP,
        Username: conf.InfluxUser,
        Password: conf.InfluxPasswd,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error connecting to the Influx server", err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    bp, err := client.NewBatchPoints(client.BatchPointsConfig{
        Database:  conf.InfluxDb,
        Precision: "s",
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error creating a NewBatchPoint", err)
    }
    for _, v := range rs.Values {
        tags := map[string]string{
            "id":    id,
            "mtype": mtype,
        }
        fields := map[string]interface{}{
            avgpcpu: v.MetricValue,
        }
        pt, err := client.NewPoint(
            tablename,
            tags,
            fields,
            time.Unix(v.MetricTime, 0),
        )
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error creating NewPoint ", err)
        }
        bp.AddPoint(pt)
        //      f, _ := pt.Fields()
        //      log.Printf("adding point %s >> %v >> %s >> %d >> %v", pt.Name(), pt.Tags(), pt.Time(), pt.UnixNano(), f)
    }
    if err := c.Write(bp); err != nil {
        log.Println("Error writing to Influx", err)
    }

}
```

In general, the Resultset will have about 4200 rows (sometimes its in lower 100s), and each of those is converted to a BatchPoint comprising two string tags, and one float field. The metric is retrieved from Cloudwatch and pushed into Influx, with the SaveMetricsToInflux method called in a loop, once per EC2 instance.

The problem I am facing is that almost every time, the write operation returns with a Partial Write error. The details of the error vary from attempt to next.

As an example, the following error came during my latest run (attempting to write 196 records):

> Error writing to Influx {"error":"partial write:\nunable to parse
>   'metrics,id=i-094385fbc09268fd6,mtype=ec2-cpu avg-pcpu=1.662-cpu
>   avg-pcpu=1.802 1494277200': invalid number\nunable to parse '6
>   1494244500': invalid field format\nunable to parse
>   'metrics,id=i-094385fbc09268fd6,mtype=ec': missing fields"}

As is seen, this looks like data corruption. First I thought that this was because of too many records being sent, but as seen in the last example above, it occurs also for low 100 records too.

Next, I thought, I might be corrupting the memory someway in my code. So I logged out each BatchPoint as it was added, and also logged out the HTTP Query data (from the Influx golang client) of the records being sent by HTTP. The data in both those places was pristine and correct, and yet I received the error.

The partial writes have so far resulted in a loss of less than a 100 records. Inside the Influxdb, this is also messing up my data by creating invalid measurements and data:

```
> show measurements
name: measurements
name
----
metricd01d7a  <-- this is invalid
metrics       <-- valid
s             <-- this is invalid

> select count(*) from metrics group by mtype
name: metrics
tags: mtype=             <-- this is invalid
time count_avg-pcpu
---- --------------
0    4

name: metrics
tags: mtype=ec2-cec2-cpu <-- this is invalid
time count_avg-pcpu
---- --------------
0    1

name: metrics            <-- valid
tags: mtype=ec2-cpu
time count_avg-pcpu
---- --------------
0    42210
```

Since I have not seen this issue widely reported, I have to assume this is uniquely occurring in my environment. In a previous development, I had used node.js and javascript API to write to the same InfluxDB (with about the same rows) without this issue occurring. Which seems to put the blame back onto the golang code I have written.

I am stumped on what else to do to debug this issue further. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How if you split the write operation, e.g. every 100 points, call `c.Write(bp)` and then recreate new batch points?

Comment: Is there a significance to the value 100? While I could try that, it seems to be a random number. From the documentation for the client, the golang client is supposed to handle the http limits without needing explicit splitting. In fact, the reference example has 1000 points added at a time.

Comment: No, you can try even with 1000, but I think lower number is better for starting point, since we don't know what the exact problem. Where on the documentation said that the client will handle http limits for you? Looking at the `client.go`, it simply send the data through `POST` request. One more poin, how did you define and fill the data to `ResultSet`? Is it used concurrently?

Comment: All of my code is running sequentially. The ResultSet is populated first, then sequentially, it is passed into this function to be written. I will try restricting the count to 100 and see if it helps.